# Jmeter Error While Recording

Tags: java, jmeter

I am getting below error in browser while recording an application in `JMeter`.

> org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://access.xyz.com refused at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:190) at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294) at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643) at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479) at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906) at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805) at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:481) at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:298) at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74) at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105) at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:236) Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:127) at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180) ... 10 more

I am giving the address as `Localhost` and port as `8080`.
I am using `JMeter 2.11` and it is working fine for all other applications.
Only while recording this particular application I am getting above error.

Comment: And the URL is working on your browser? Because the error says it is not able to connect to access.xyz.com port 80

Comment: I am able to access the application in browser.

Comment: Only while recording m getting above error. For recording I am giving address as localhost and port as 8080 as mentioned in Jmeter proxy settings.

Answer (score 0):

Your stack trace says in the first line:

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://access.xyz.com refused
```

In your description after the stack trace you said the service was on localhost port 8080.  The problem is you are requesting a URL with no service behind it.  Change the URL you are querying to:

```
http://localhost:8080
```

or if you've hacked your HOSTS file to have `access.xyz.com` resolve to localhost, then you need to specify the port number in your URL like this:

```
http://access.xyz.com:8080
```

Without the `:8080`, the protocol `http` uses the default port of 80.  Similarly, the default port for the protocol `https` (SSL) is 443.  If you use anything other than the default port, you have to explicitly set the port in the URL.

Comment: Hi Berin,

I am getting the same error as above even when recording google.com using localhost and 8080